# Create an SSL certificate for a dev site running a watch on port 3000

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, localhost, mamp

I understand that there is a flag to allow insecure localhost, but how do we bypass the security warnings for a dev site that is using MAMP, and is running some type of webpack watch on port 3000.

for example if I have `dev.example` working with a cert, how do I get a cert for `dev.example:3000` or at least bypass the security warning?

I am running a webpack/wordpress instance on MAMP on windows.